# SwiftUI : I can't make ZStack view in NavigationLink's Screen

Tags: swiftui, view, swiftui-navigationlink

**This is my NavigationLink DetailView,**

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddChildrenView: View {

@State var word : String = ""
@State var meaning : String = ""
@State var isShowAlert : Bool = false
@State var isClicked : Bool = false

@EnvironmentObject var itemModel : ItemModel

var item : Item

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        if item.children.count == 0 {
            NochildrenView()
        }
        List {
            ForEach(item.children) { child in
                WordListRowView(children: child)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.3)) {
                            itemModel.favoriteChildren(item: item, children: child)
                        }
                    }
            }
            .onDelete { indexSet in
                itemModel.deleteChildren1(item: item, indexSet: indexSet)
            }
        }
        .id(UUID())
    }
    
    .navigationBarTitle("\(item.group!)'s Words")
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                            
    HStack {
        Button(action: {
            addChildren()
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "plus")
        })
        
        Button(action: {
            itemModel.shuffleChildren(item: item)
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "shuffle")
        })
                      
        NavigationLink(destination: FlashCardView(item: item)) {
            Image(systemName: "play.rectangle")
        }
        .disabled(item.children.isEmpty)
    })
}
```

}

```
extension AddChildrenView {
    func addChildren() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Saving word", message: "Type word and meaning ", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    alert.addTextField { word in
        word.placeholder = "Type a word"
    }
    
    alert.addTextField { meaning in
        meaning.placeholder = "a meaning of word"
    }
    
    let addfolderAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default, handler: {
        (_) in
        self.word = alert.textFields![0].text!
        self.meaning = alert.textFields![1].text!
        itemModel.addNewChildren(item: item, word: word, meaning: meaning)
    })
    
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: {
        (_) in
    })
    
    alert.addAction(addfolderAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    
    UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

**This is MotherView with NavigationLink,**

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {

@State var folderName : String = ""

@EnvironmentObject var itemModel : ItemModel

var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        ZStack {
            if itemModel.items.count == 0 {
                NoItemView()
            }
            List{
                ForEach(itemModel.items) {item in
                    if let group = item.group {
                        NavigationLink(destination: {
                            AddChildrenView(item : item)
                        }, label: {
                            HStack{
                                Image(systemName: "folder")
                                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                                Text(group)
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .lineLimit(1)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
                .onMove(perform: itemModel.moveItem)
                .onDelete(perform: itemModel.deleteItem)
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
        }
            
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        .navigationTitle("SelfDic ")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            Button(action: {
                addFolderView()
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "folder.badge.plus")
        }))
        .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton())
    }
}
}

extension HomeView {

func addFolderView() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Saving folder", message: "Type a name of folder ", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    alert.addTextField { name in
        name.placeholder = "folder's name"
    }
    
    let addfolderAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default, handler: {
        (_) in
        self.folderName = alert.textFields![0].text!
        itemModel.addNewFolder(text: folderName)
    })
    
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: {
        (_) in
    })
    alert.addAction(addfolderAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    


    UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}
```

**I wanted to use Zstack in my linked View

The logic is that, If there is no item.children, I will show NoChildrenView().

But, It doesn't work.
How can I treat this problem?**
I hope I can solve this!
Thank you all senior developers!!

Comment: There are missing types here, so no one can compile your code to try it. Can you remove what is superfluous to the issue and include the missing types to make a [mre]? Also, likely unrelated to your issue, but why are you using `id(UUID())` on your list?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! that is for List id, when I didn't use it, there was some delay, so I did that to give id for each of list in my mother and child view!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully check all code, but in `AddChildrenView` there might be missing an `else`. Like you have it now the empty list will be always shown above your `NochildrenView()`

```
    if item.children.count == 0 {
        NochildrenView()
    } else {   // here
    ...
```

Comment: OMG! Jesus, Chris! Thank you so much one more time. I hope I can follow your instagram. Surely if you don't mind. I'm begineer developer. so please understand my side! and Thank you ! and IT WORKS!!!!

Comment: Happy to help. And happy if you accept my answer as correct.